# Simulate multi-touch when single touch is detected

Tags: android

I'm try do simulate a two-fingers action when one-finger is detected, I successfully make a one-finger touch with GestudeDescription and I know that I can't do two-fingers with it but I wandering if I can make it think I'm using the two-fingers doing the same action(swipe for exemple) when I use only one finger.

Comment: Hi, if you read that, know that I've found the truth, there is no possibility at all to simulate two-finger gesture other than zoom, I'll try to remember this question exist in the future and give an answer if this feature becomes available.